# $ionicPosition.offset and $ionicPosition.position causing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined"

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to get the position and offset of a dragged list item on release.

However, both $ionicPosition.offset and $ionicPosition.position both return "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined.

I've included a rudimentary code snippet. Thanks in advance!

```js
var data = {
  "week": [{
    "name": "Monday",
    "activities": [{
      "name": "Go running",
      "shortname": "go_running"
    }, {
      "name": "Wash clothes",
      "shortname": "wash_clothes"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Tuesday",
    "activities": [{
      "name": "Holiday shopping",
      "shortname": "holiday_shopping"
    }, {
      "name": "Clean bike",
      "shortname": "clean_bike"
    }]
  }]
}

var app = angular.module('activityplan', ['ionic']);

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});

app.controller('PlanController', ['$scope','$ionicPosition', function($scope,$ionicPosition) {

  $scope.days = data.week;
  $scope.releaseTest = function(a) {
    console.log($ionicPosition.offset(a));
    console.log($ionicPosition.position(a));
  }
  
  $scope.moveActivity = function(activity, day, fromIndex, toIndex) {

     day.activities.splice(fromIndex, 1);
    day.activities.splice(toIndex, 0, activity);
    

  };

}]);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Activity plan</title> 

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="activityplan">

  <ion-content ng-controller="PlanController" style="width:360px;"> 
     
      <div ng-repeat="day in days">

        <div class="item item-divider item-dark">
          <b>{{ day.name }}</b>
        </div>

        <ion-list ng-controller="PlanController" show-reorder="true" can-swipe="true">
          <ion-item class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="activity in day.activities track by $index" on-release="releaseTest(activity)">
            {{ activity.name }}
            <ion-option-button class="button-assertive icon ion-trash-a" ng-click=""></ion-option-button>
            <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reorder="moveActivity(activity,day,$fromIndex,$toIndex)"></ion-reorder>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>

      </div>

    </ion-content>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it all wrong. Method `offset(element)` and `position(element)` of [$ionicPosition](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPosition/) expects DOM element to be *part of* parameter.

In your case you are passing the JavaScript object from mark-up thats why its failing.

> **position(element)** : 
>   Get the current coordinates of the element, relative to the offset parent. Read-only equivalent of jQuery’s position function.

Its fact that it is very poorly documented in ionic docs.

What I figured out after digging through source code that these methods are jQuery equivalent and jQuery always wraps the matched element inside array, therefore parameter should be an **array** with 0th index pointing to actual dom as shown below

```js
var element = document.getElementById(id);
var offset = $ionicPosition.offset([element]); 
/*it returns the offset of param[0] 
where param is the parameter passed to this function
*/

/*note that we need to wrap the dom element inside array as these methods are inspired from jQuery 
and jQuery wraps the matched element inside array 
  
If you are using AngularJS's jqLite, please verify if actual DOM is in array 0th position or not

*/
```

Comment: No offence, but why the down-vote without any explanation. May be you don't understand it or if you have better solution, post it...